# How do I change text to bold w/o changing font

Tags: java, apache-poi

I can set text bold with code:

```
XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
XSSFCellStyle bold = workbook.createCellStyle();
bold.setFont(font);
...
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Yes, cell has bold style, but it has another font. It has `Calibri` (size: 11). If I create cell without style, I get for this cell: `Liberation Sans` (size: 10).

OK, then I try other way:

```
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.STRING);
cell.setCellValue("test");
// Crash
// XSSFCellStyle style = row.getRowStyle();
XSSFCellStyle style = row.getCell(0).getCellStyle();    
XSSFFont font = style.getFont();
font.setBold(true);
style.setFont(font);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

No diffs. I get `Calibri` (size: 11).

But why? And how I can fix it? I want that all cells (with bold or without bold) has same font name and size. I do not want manual set font.

Comment: Is the bold font available on your system ? Sounds like a fallback

Comment: Yes, I can: open xls file, press `ctrl + b` and see bold text.

Comment: Don't confuse a _font_ with a _typeface_.  Calibri is a _typeface_, which is made up of a collection of _fonts_.  If a bold font doesn't exist in the typeface, it may fallback to another typeface, possibly in the same font family, which does have a bold font (as @baao suggested).

Comment: Guys, my bad. It's `LibreOffice` issue. I have installed on my unix only LibreOffice. But If I same file upload to `onedrive` and open it in `Excel Online`, I see all strings correctly - `Calibri` (11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `LibreOffice` issue, that I used to open xlsx-files.